# Show the host builder node name on the Blue Ocean Pipeline page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I was wondering if that is possible to show the information about the host builder machine on the Pipeline page of the Blue Ocean for the builds. Since the build pick the available builder to run on, it would be handy to have that info right on that page rather than following a couple of clicks to find that info out (see the attached image).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think "the host builder machine" is a single agent? Each stage can run on a different agent (heck, you can have multiple agents within a stage if you are so inclined) - which one would you expect to see at the pipeline level?

Comment: Good point. In our case all the work is happening on one machine, but considering that different stages could run on different machines, I wonder if we could show the complete list of all that will be involved or at least the first one it was kicked on.